# Get details for each link in structural navigation in SP2013

Tags: 2013, navigation

Is there any way of programatically getting all the details for all the links in SP2013 structural navigation like Link Title, URL, Description & Audience 
as the one I am working with has around 30-40 links and differnt audience targeting for multiple links?

Otherwise getting details by clicking on each link is a cumbersome task to do.

Note - I am not using managed metadata navigation & having Site collection admin rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below REST url in your AJAX call. And let me know if its working :

```
http://<yoursite>/_api/navigation/menustate?mapprovidername='CurrentNavigation'
```